# how to increase image resolution while converting canvas to image

Tags: jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas library for converting and downloading html page to image.
Here is my code

```
 $("#fullPageScreenshot").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('pageBody'),{
        onrendered: function (canvas) {

            var img=canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = img;
            a.download = 'FullPageScreenshot.jpg';
            a.click();
        }
    });
})
```

But the problem is image quality is very low and blurry. plz anyone help me..

Comment: what does _increase image resolution_ mean? Stretch the image or magically improve the image quality?

Comment: the image is downloading is very poor in quality.

Comment: as a reference to convert page to image http://infoheap.com/convert-html-canvas-to-png-image/...it may give u clear image and download code will be same..

Comment: @Debin the linnk u have given is not opening.http://infoheap.com/iterate-python-dictionary-by-sorted-values/ this is opening instead

Comment: use  http://infoheap.com/convert-html-canvas-to-png-image/ only